# Force close while calling mainactivity from widget (android)

Tags: android, widget

Iam creating a simple widget, by this widget i want to open my mainactivity.

Iam sending a unique key from my widget class to check whether my mainactivity is called via widget or not.

But as soon as i clicked on my widget my mainactivity get force close.

here is code of my widget class...

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] widgets) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int numofWidgets = widgets.length;
    for(int i=0;i<numofWidgets;i++){
        int widget = widgets[i];
        Intent in = new Intent(context, EmergencyButton.class);
        in.putExtra("uniquevalue", "widget");
        PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, in, 0);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetlayout);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingintent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widget, views);
    }
}
```

And Here is my code of mainactivity where iam checking whether called came from widget or not

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity); 
     Intent intentwidget = this.getIntent();
    if(intentwidget !=null)
    {
      String widgetdata = "nothing";
      widgetdata = intentwidget.getExtras().getString("uniquevalue");//this is line 29 
      if(widgetdata.equals("widget"))
        {

        }
    }
```

}

And here is my logcat

```
11-04 14:57:14.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1701): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 14:57:14.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1701): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activityComponentInfo{com.appsionlabs.googlemapv2/com.appsionlabs.googlemapv2.EmergencyButton}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-04 14:57:14.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at          android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
11-04 14:57:14.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-04 14:57:14.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-04 14:57:14.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-04 14:57:14.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-04 14:57:14.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-04 14:57:14.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-04 14:57:14.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 14:57:14.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-04 14:57:14.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-04 14:57:14.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-04 14:57:14.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 14:57:14.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1701): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-04 14:57:14.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at com.appsionlabs.googlemapv2.EmergencyButton.onCreate(EmergencyButton.java:29)
11-04 14:57:14.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-04 14:57:14.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1701):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

Comment: widgetdata = intentwidget.getExtras().getString("uniquevalue");

Comment: is it still not working?

Comment: nope.. it still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this below instead of  `Intent intentwidget = this.getIntent();`

```
Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {
            widgetdata = extras.getString("uniquevalue");
        }
```

The difference is the `Bundle`.

Comment: Thanks @silivia_aut this format worked... but i still wants to know, what happened with my previous code, they are doing same thing, where i was wrong ???

Comment: you can't get the data directly from the intent. you have to put it in bundle first and then get the string.

Comment: But not with this method he wrote.

Comment: @silvia_aut `getIntent().getStringExtra("uniquevalue")` will work

Comment: @silvia_aut even this works `getIntent().getExtras().getString("uniquevalue")`

Comment: @Raghunandan and silvia_aut i have use this method (getIntent().getExtras().getString("uniquevalue")) in my previous application .. that time it worked fine, but now it giving me force close error, but now when i get extras in separate bundle everything work fine.

Comment: @ShajiThornBlue what do you see did you try to set the string to textview

Comment: @Raghunandan yaa after calling from widget i set my string to textview just to check whether my application get a successful call from widget

Comment: @ShajiThornBlue ok so do you see the text in text view?

Comment: @Raghunandan when i get extras in my separate bundle i  see text in my textview.

Answer (score 2):

You have this

```
 et1.setText(widgetdata);
```

But `et1` is not initialized. Initialize `et1`.

Edit:

Use the below and try

```
  Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
  if (extras != null) {
        widgetdata = extras.getString("uniquevalue");
  }
```

Comment: et1 is not creating force close error.. 
widgetdata = intentwidget.getExtras().getString("uniquevalue");
whenever i tried to getextras from widget this line of code create force close error

Comment: @ShajiThornBlue that means your widgetdata is null

Comment: is the code in `EmergencyButton.java` is that your main activity

Comment: yup emergencybutton is my mainactivity

Comment: @ShajiThornBlue comment that line 29 see if it works just to test

Comment: yup now app is working fine.. but still i want to check whether my code is called from widget or not.. how to do that ???

Answer (score 0):

et1 is null at that position.

get the et1 id and then set the text.